# PhoneGap: How to display/interact with native UI components in Android

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I needed to display native controls along with HTML in android.

That is, i wanted to display the textcontrol, tabcontrol, menu etc along with the html in the index.html.

Please help how do i go about this.

thanks
Jaskaran

Comment: see http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36868306/UI%20Development%20using%20jQueryMobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to check the phonegap plugins at github. If you dont find what you are looking for, then you may develop the required plugin. 
Cheers